# How do I fix Akka plugin is not registered in Play assembly?

Tags: maven, playframework, akka

I have built a Play assembly in Maven using

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>play2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-beta1</version>
</plugin>
```

via the maven-shade-plugin with entry point play.core.server.NettyServer. When I try to run it using

```
java -Dhttp-port=7000 -jar p3-users-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-allinone.jar
```

I get

```
Play server process ID is 2924
Oops, cannot start the server.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Akka plugin is not registered.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka$$anonfun$system$2.apply(Akka.scala:25)
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka$$anonfun$system$2.apply(Akka.scala:25)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka$.system(Akka.scala:24)
    at securesocial.core.UserServicePlugin.onStart(UserService.scala:129)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
    at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:52)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:243)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:279)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:274)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:274)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
```

I am not sure what 'registered' is supposed to mean. Is this a missing dependency somewhere, or some other configuration problem?

As an aside, I previously built the assembly in SBT using the sbt-assembly-plugin, and it all seemed to work fine, so I know it's possible to build an uber-jar for a Play application. However, the sbt-assembly-plugin seems to have some serious algorithmic problems, causing it to take 20 times longer to build assemblies than the maven-shade-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I seem to have manually fixed the problem.

According to https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaPlugins plugins are registered in conf/play.plugins. I could see that Akka was missing from that, but was not sure why. Somehow the sbt-assembly-plugin did the right thing, but the maven-shade-plugin did not.

I searched my target directory for more play.plugins files, and found a couple under streams/... and one included a definition for

```
1000:play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaPlugin
```

so I added that, and other definitions to my conf/play.plugins file. I am not sure if this is something that the play2-maven-plugin should be handling or not. Likely SBT has a built in awareness of Play projects, and handled the Play plugin registrations properly.

Anyway, this is more of a workaround than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no AkkaPlugin in Play! `2.4.x`. I don't use `2.4.x`, so I don't know if it was moved somewhere or just removed from `play/api/libs/concurrent/Akka.scala` file.

Could you provide simple test project, or a least your dependencies and plugins configuration in `pom.xml` file?

Comment: We are still using Play 2.2.1. It would be nice to upgrade to Play 2.4 or later, but we're just not there yet. Do you still want to see the POM?

Comment: Do you still need help?